# Change default status and replace the icon for an hamburger menu

Tags: customization, menus

When the screen becomes too small (i.e. if I restrict the browser window, or if I open my website from mobile) the menu becomes an hamburger (☰). I want to know how to do the following two things:

1. Change the default status of the menu from the "not toggled" status (when you can only see ☰) to the "toggled" status (when you can see the whole opened menu, and tapping on ☰ closes it).
2. Change the symbol from ☰ to another, perhaps something like "☰ MENU" or perhaps an entirely different thing.

How can I do these things? If it helps, I am using the Illustratr theme and my website (under construction) is https://cesaregardito.eu

Comment: This question is not about wordpress itself, but about the Illustratr theme. Its author should be able to help you

Comment: @cjbj I don't know, the hamburger menu feature is present in almost every theme I have seen so far. I am not sure it's a theme-specific thing.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 The problem is that most likely every theme handles this logic differently. Some might do it CSS only, some with heavy jQuery, some with vanilla JS. Some have filters, other don't. That is why this question is theme-specific (in my eyes).

Comment: @kero oh okay, I see!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the current icon by css and then you can add your new icon in the .menu-toggle button with background-image.

the css is below;

```
.genericon-menu:before{
content: " ";
}
.main-navigation .menu-toggle{
background-image: url(/*image url*/);
background-size: contain;
}
```